# 2 or more continious features in Tree classification

Tags: classification, cart, continuous-data

If a training set has a continious feature, some texts recommend that first the dataset is sorted based on the continious feature, and then  split points are chosen. What I am not sure about, is how to handle a case where the training set has more than one continious feature? How can that be sorted and then information gains compared?

Comment: All the tree programs that I am familiar with (SAS, and several in R) will handle the sorting for you.  I've never seen a recommendation to sort first. That might be just to save computer time or something.  

Can you give more detail of who recommends this and why?

Comment: @PeterFlom I am interested to understand on a theoretical level, as for example, shown https://youtu.be/_L39rN6gz7Y. I agree that programs/tools may do this automatically.

Comment: Are you referring to timestamp 10:00?  That sorting is just to make finding the impurity-optimal threshold easier, but it can be done independently for each feature.

Comment: @BenReiniger, so you suggest that if we have 5 countinous features, we would need to sort the dataset 5 times to calculate impurity for each of the continuous features?

Comment: @Karl17302 yes, although sorting "the dataset" can be limited to the feature in question at the time and target column